# When does this equation have positive roots?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, roots

I am reading a paper where the author states (without proofing) that the equation

$$
{x}^2 \left(1-2 \sqrt{2}\, {x} \right) \sin ^2(\psi )-{y}^2
   \left(1-2 \sqrt{2} \,{y} \right)=0
$$

has no positive roots for $y<3\sqrt{2}$ unless $\sin(\psi)>3\sqrt{2}\,y\sqrt{3(1-2\sqrt{2}\,y)}$

Could someone please explain why is this true?

Comment: Do we assume $y>0$?

Comment: @iamvegan, yes.

Comment: @iamvegan, Also the paper is really old and the text is not very clear so I am not sure whether the condition is $y<3 \sqrt{2}$ or $y<(3 \sqrt{2})^{-1}$.

Comment: Are there more assumptions? When $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ it looks like there is a positive root $x$.

Comment: @iamvegan, No, but if there is a positive root for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ then the condition is $y<(3 \sqrt{2})^{-1}$ not $y<3 \sqrt{2}$ as I said the paper is very old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $y<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$ is fixed. Then define
\begin{align*}
f(x)&={x}^2 \left(1-2 \sqrt{2}\, {x} \right) \sin ^2(\psi )-{y}^2
   \left(1-2 \sqrt{2} \,{y} \right)\\
f'(x)&=\left(2x -6 \sqrt{2}\, x^2 \right) \sin ^2(\psi )
\end{align*}
Since $f$ is concave down the maximum value occurs at $x_0=\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{2}}$. Plugging it in $f(x)$ gives us
\begin{align*}
f(x_0)&= \frac{\sin ^2(\psi )}{54}-{y}^2
   \left(1-2 \sqrt{2} \,{y} \right)
\end{align*}

If $\sin(\psi)<3\sqrt{2}\,y\sqrt{3(1-2\sqrt{2}\,y)}$ then the maximum value of this function is negative hence there is no roots.

Comment: In the first line is it $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$ or $\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}}$?.

Comment: I think my proof is correct for $y < \frac1{2\sqrt2}$. If you want to take a smaller upper bound for $y$ like $\frac1{3\sqrt2}$ you can.